# Swift: Accessing OS X address book: "ABPerson is not convertible to ABPerson"

Tags: xcode, swift, abperson

I am accessing the OS X address book like so:

```
if let book = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook() { 
    let people = book.people() as [ABPerson]
    for person in people {
        // Now I want to get the person's image to some variable
        ABPersonCopyImageData(person) // compile error
    }
}
```

Xcode says 'ABPerson' is not convertible to 'ABPerson'.

What's wrong with that?

Thanks in advance,
Kim

Comment: I can't tell you why, but it compiles if you replace `as [ABPerson]` by `as [ABPersonRef]`. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Totally weird to me. With [ABPerson]

person.valueForProperty(kABFirstNameProperty)

works fine. Just for an example.